# Can automorphism equivalence in a free group be detected in a nilpotent quotient?

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups, nilpotent-groups, automorphisms

If $G$ is a group and $g_1, g_2 \in G$ let us write $g_1 \sim g_2$ if there is an automorphism $\alpha \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ such that $g_1^\alpha = g_2$.

Let $F = F_2$ be the free group on two generators. Let $(\gamma_n(F))_{n=1}^\infty$ denote the lower central series of $F$. Let $w_1, w_2 \in F$. Suppose that, for every integer $n$, $$(w_1 \bmod \gamma_n(F)) \sim (w_2 \bmod \gamma_n(F)).$$ Does it follow that $w_1 \sim w_2$?

This question is interesting to me because a positive answer sounds too good to be true, and yet equally I would be fascinated to see an offending pair of words $w_1, w_2$. Not sure if there is research out there about this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is extremely false due to the following basic fact about nilpotent groups:

**Theorem**: Let $N$ be a finitely generated nilpotent group and let $f\colon N \rightarrow N$ be a homomorphism.  Then $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if the induced map $f_{\ast}\colon N^{\text{ab}} \rightarrow N^{\text{ab}}$ on the abelianization is an isomorphism.

This can be proved by induction on the degree of nilpotence of $N$.  For instance, I wrote out a proof in Theorem 8.1 of my paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.2104).

Now let $F$ be free on $x$ and $y$.  Consider some $w \in F$ that maps to the same element of $F^{\text{ab}} = \mathbb{Z}^2$ as $x$.  Define an endomorphism $f\colon F \rightarrow F$ taking $x$ to $w$ and $y$ to $y$.  Then $f$ is almost certainly not an automorphism of $F$, but by the above theorem it induces an isomorphism $F/\gamma_n(F) \rightarrow F/\gamma_n(F)$ for all $n$.  It follows that $x$ and $w$ are equivalent modulo $\gamma_n(F)$ for all $n$, but they are probably not equivalent in $F$ (for instance, it is easy to arrange such a $w$ that does not lie in part of a free basis for $F$).

Note: I had originally written something stronger than the above in haste.

Comment: I can't open your paper. But this fact follows from two old facts (1) f.g. nilpotent implies Hopfian (2) if $H$ is a subgroup of an arbitrary nilpotent group $G$, $H=G$ iff $H[G,G]=G$. From (2) it follows that if $f:G\to H$ is a homomorphism between arbitrary nilpotent groups, $f$ is surjective iff the induced homomorphism of abelianizations is surjective. Applied to endomorphisms of f.g. nilpotent groups, and using Hopfianity, we get the result.

Comment: @YCor: I was definitely not claiming that this was due to me (which is why I said "For instance, I wrote out a proof...").  The only reason I gave a reference to my old paper (which also emphasized that we were not the first to notice it) was that I happened to know a precise location where exactly this statement was proven.

Comment: (ps: was there a reason you couldn't open it?  I thought the arXiv was good at generating pdf files that were easily read on most computers.)

Comment: Thanks! By the way, "not part of a free basis" is just a restatement of "not equivalent to $x$".

Comment: @SeanEberhard: Thanks, happy to help!

Comment: @AndyPutman it's not a pdf. Better provide the arXiv link.

Comment: @Ycor: I think I did provide the arXiv link?  When I click on it, it goes right to the arXiv.  Here's the link, copied from my answer: https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.2104

Comment: Oh yes sorry for the noise, the link is OK. For some reason, the first time, I downloaded a document that I cannot open.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a result of Nielsen states that the set of primitive elements $w$ such that $w$ and $x$ map to the same same element of $\mathbb Z^2$ is just the conjugacy class of $x$. (This is special to the rank-two free group.) It follows that $w = x^2 y x^{-1} y^{-1}$ is not primitive. Here "primitive" means "equivalent to $x$ by an automorphism", or equivalently "part of a free basis".

Comment: @SeanEberhard: that's correct. You can also check directly that $w$ is primitive using Whitehead's algorithm: the Whitehead graph of $w$ is two triangles glued along  one side; since this doesn't have a cut vertex, Whitehead's lemma implies that $w$ is not primitive.